# How to sort a table contents according to values given in a select box in php?

Tags: php

I have a table containing some fields like name,address,item status in a table. I have values like Item Picked, Item Not Picked.

I have a select box like given below :

```
<select name="option" class="optionn">
     <option value="">All</option>
     <option value="itempicked">Item Picked</option>
     <option value="itemnotpicked">Item Not Picked</option>
</select>
```

I want to sort the table contents according to the selected value in the select box.

How to do this ? Can anyone say how to do this ?

Comment: try to use ajax pass selected value and get html response to set in table

Answer (score 0):

```
<select name="option" class="optionn" id="items">
 <option value="">All</option>
 <option value="itempicked">Item Picked</option>
 <option value="itemnotpicked">Item Not Picked</option>
</select>

 $.ajax({
 url : 'example.php',
 data:{
    item:$('#items').val()
 },
 type: 'POST',
 success: function(result){
    console.log(result); // result set in table
 }
})
```

in example.php file write query to get sorting data

```
Ex. $query = "SELECT * FROM items WHERE items = ".$_POST['item'];
```

Comment: ajax code should be written  inside select onchange

Comment: I have written it.. But nothing is getting printed in the console

Comment: in example.php file simple echo something and then show in console. url path set or not.

Answer (score 0):

This is just the example it's not your answer i hope it's help you.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
 <head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title></title>
 </head>
 <body>
<div class="wrapper">
  <div>
  <select class="options" name="">
    <option value="1">item_1</option>
    <option value="1">item_2</option>
    <option value="1">item_3</option>
  </select>
</div>
</div>
<button type="button" class="addme" name="button">Add More</button>
 </body>
 <script src="https://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jQuery/jquery-3.1.1.min.js"> </script>
  <script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('.addme').click(function(){
    $.ajax({
      url:'getData.php',
      type:'GET',
      success:function(result){
          console.log(result);
      }
    })
  });
});
```

getData.php File

```
$query = "select * from items";
$row = mysql_query($query);

echo "<select>";

while($data = mysql_fetch_array($row)){

echo "<option>".$data['item_name']."</option>";

}

echo "</select>";
```